Empirical density estimate concentration bound?
I have a continuous distribution $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$. I have a sample $S$ of size $n$ from $\mu$. Let $B_{\delta}(x)$ be a $\delta$-ball around $x$. Let $\mu(B_{\delta}(x))$ represent the probability density covered by a ball of radius $\delta$ around $x$. Let $\mu^{*}(B_{\delta}(x))$ be the empirical density estimate, defined as follows:
$$\mu^{*}(B_{\delta}(x)) = \frac{1}{|S|}|S \cap B_{\delta}(x) |$$
Is there a known bound of the following type:
$$|\mu^{*}(B_{\delta}(x)) - \mu(B_{\delta}(x))| < \frac{f(n,\delta)}{\sqrt{n}}$$
where $f(n,\delta)$ is some reasonable function. I remember seeing a result like this and would now be quite useful for me. But I cannot seem to find it. Any help, pointing to a reasonable source or the original result would be very useful.
